# Content loaded from different queries mixed up / wrong content displayed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very strange bug on my wordpress site:

in the header.php i'm loading images like that:

```
   <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'media_category',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => 'redimages' 
            )
        )
    );

    $the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query2->the_post();

            $postid = get_the_ID();

            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $postid , 'full');
            if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" class="backgroundimage"/>
            <?php endif;
        }
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```

and inside functions.php i have a custom function to load the content of a page:

```
function pf_show_page($id) {
  $post = get_post($id); 
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  echo $content;
}
```

now my problem is, that one image from the first query is always displayed, when i call the pf_show_page function, although there are no images in the pages I load. 
The strangest thing is that this only happens when the 404.php is opened, but the images show up in the header.php region.
I copied the queries from the other templates to the 404 document and it is still happening.
Maybe there's something wrong outside my template files?
Tried my best to describe my problem. Thank you for reading

Comment: Your query will always list **all** the images from that category since you haven't anyhow limited it to only look for the images only attached to the current object

Comment: Thats how its supposed to be. I have around 10 images with this category, but somehow one of them is loaded when I'm using my show_page function..